# Relationship between Spring DispatcherServlet and Filters

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

Spring MVC uses a `DispatcherServlet` to route control to an appropriate Controller. But where do filters fit into the flow? If I specify a filter to perform session management or authentication, will the filters always be called before DispatcherServlet?

My confusion comes from the fact that they both specify a URL pattern. What happens if they both provide the same url pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not really specific to Spring and Spring MVC. In general fitlers are always called *before* servlets. When you have several filters and one servlet matching given URL pattern, all filters are executed first in the order of `<filter-mapping>` definitions and the servlet is executed last.

This way you can modify the request on the fly or even ignore the servlet altogether.