# Spring MVC Execution Order: Filter and Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm developing a spring MVC application that uses a filter implementing [`javax.servlet.Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and an Interceptor extending [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html).

As far as I know, the control flow of Spring MVC is something like this:

1. Request arrives at `DispatcherServlet`.
2. `DispatcherServlet` sends it to `Interceptor` and the overrided `preHandle` method is executed.
3. Request arrives at the matching Controller.
4. After processing the request, if `postHandle` method of interceptor is also overrided Spring executes its code.
5. `DispatcherServlet` uses the view resolver and sends the model to view, rendering it.

Doing some tests I can see my filter is always executed BEFORE the `preHandle` method. It seems to be the first executed thing after `DispatcherServlet`. It's ok, but I do not find the reason for this behaviour. Someone with a good explanation?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Possibility: It's because filter is defined in `web.xml` (like `DispatcherServlet`) so Filter is executed before `DispatcherServlet`?

Comment: *It seems to be the first executed thing after `DispatcherServlet`.* This is not correct. See [servlets - Relationship between Spring DispatcherServlet and Filters - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342010/relationship-between-spring-dispatcherservlet-and-filters).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's perfectly fine as
`Filter's` are part of Servlet specification.

`Filters` are called by your `Server(tomcat)`. while Interceptors are called by `Spring`.

Comment: Thanks, reading about your comment I've found this: 

"Servlet Filters  process requests before they are sent to servlets and response after servlet code is finished and before container sends the response back to the client."

And DispatcherServlet is a Servlet so it's normal to have request filter executed before it. But also important to know response filter is executed AFTER!

Comment: *"Servlet Filters process requests before they are sent to servlets and response after servlet code is finished and before container sends the response back to the client."* comes from [Java Servlet Filter Example Tutorial - JournalDev](https://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial).